# Integral over domain enclosed by curves

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

Integrate the following function over the domain $D$ which is limited by the curves $xy=1, xy=2, y-x=1, y-x=3.$
\begin{equation}
\int\int_{D} (x+y)dxdy
\end{equation}

I have drawn out the domain and I have found all the points of intersection between the curves.  However, it seems as though maybe a variable change would make this problem easier and simplify the integration bounds.

Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: The obvious thing to try first is a change of variables that turns the domain into a rectangle. $D$ is bounded by level curves of a couple of functions. Try starting with those.

Comment: OK. But what is the strategy to choose this change of variables.  I know that I am hoping to make the domain square, but im not sure what variable change to make

Comment: There is not a "strategy" that works every time, I'm afraid. In your case, by the form of your domain $D$, I'd try with the substitution $u = xy$ and $v = y-x$.

Comment: With this variable change does it mean I must first find the determinant of the Jacobian Matrix of the transformation, but then use its inverse in the calculation?

Comment: That’s right. Leave it in terms of $x$ and $y$ for as long as possible to simplify your calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let $u=xy$ and $v=y-x$, we have 
\begin{align}
  & \frac{\partial (u,v)}{\partial (x,y)}=\left| \begin{matrix}
   y & x  \\
   -1 & 1  \\
\end{matrix} \right|=x+y\Rightarrow J=\frac{1}{x+y} \\ 
 & \int_{1}^{2}{\int_{1}^{3}{dvdu}}=6 \\ 
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you! The reason for taking the inverse of the jacobian is because we want to explicit x and y in terms of u and v, correct?

Comment: yes exactly . :)

Answer (score 0):

For a sensible variable change I would suggest using $xy$ as one variable and then you can probably work it out.